# Overlap ImageView on top of another view that has border added to it

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I want to make a ListView item which upon selection looks like this. How can I make the checkmark appear on top right corner of UI?
[image]

Code So far

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/checkmark"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_check_mark"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/match_constraint"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ble_multiple_device_select_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingVertical="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/video_dimen_4"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/video_dimen_4"
            android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/video_dimen_12"
            android:src="@color/black" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Text 1"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Text 2"
                android:textSize="13sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/icn_add" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm able to place it on the top right but there are 2 problems with this approach

1. the vector image that I've provided has a transparent tick mark so  I could see the border through the checkmark
2. I'm currently solving this problem by giving the entire layout a to, end padding and using clipToPadding="false". This approach feels ickey I need to add un-necessary padding to the entire layout

This is what my implementation looks so far

[image]

Comment: Can you share your codes what you have done already?

Comment: Sure I'll update the question @TicherhazFreePalestine